# What's the best way to deal with bad exec files after loading an Intel-based Time Machine backup into an M1 chip computer?

Tags: apple-m1, apple-silicon, timemachine

I've loaded a copy of my Intel-based mac into an M1 chip mac through Time Machine. However, I've been constantly running into bad CPU type files and needing to reinstall some apps that are built for Apple silicon. (I also feel like my laptop's battery has noticeably decreased since loading that Time Machine backup.) I didn't download Rosetta because I feel like that would make runtimes slower, and all the apps I need should have a native version published (please correct me if I'm wrong).
It's hard to get working versions of coding-related things though, like homebrew that won't install unless I specify a certain path. At this point, would I be better off just by starting fresh and download those programs as needed? As a programming newbie, I'm not sure which is better - trying to delete the non-working Intel programs (which I have yet to figure out since most uninstall programs are also Intel-based), or wiping my computer and download the Apple silicon ones right from the start.
Thanks for any tips in advance!

I've tried to delete and reinstall apps, which worked. Wasn't that successful with programs like Git since the uninstall program is in Intel.

Answer (score 0):

Downliad and install all the programs you need for the M1 chip.

Then restore your data from the backup.

Trying to run intel based programs on an M1 is just costing you time.